# How to change name of columns if it contains specific text

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I go about changing the text in columns? for e.g instead of MAC000306_Std_E_Affluent, it'll be affluent. I would like to change all the names to the last name. So ideally I'd end up with columns printing Affluent, Comfortable, [pic of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD5ks.jpg)and Adversity.

Comment: But then you'll have several columns with the same name, since the last word is shared by some columns. How would you tell them apart?

Comment: Yeh you're right, luckily im looking for aggregate of the same households. however the problem I'm having is it duplicating the houses now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your dataframe is called `df`.

1. we can retrieve the column names with `df.columns`.
2. we use the `str.split` function and split on `_`. This returns a list from which we select the last item. We save this item together with the old name in a dictionary.
3. Now the dictionary can be supplied to `df.rename` to rename the columns.

I used a [Dict Comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) to wrap most of the logic in one line.

```py
column_name_mapping = {old_name: old_name.split('_')[-1] for old_name in df.columns}
df = df.rename(columns=column_name_mapping)
```

---

Please update your question so that it provides a minimal code example that can be copied and used for testing. This will also ensure that your question is helpful to others in the future. Linked images are prone to "disappear" ;-)

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use split("_") and get the last element with [-1] as the new name of your column

```
>>>string="MAC0999_STD_F_ColumnName"
>>>string.split("_") 
['MAC0999', 'STD','F', 'ColumnName'] 
>>>NewColumnName=string.split("_")[-1] 
>>>NewColumnName
'ColumnName'´
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another solution , although it is similar (one way or another) with the one provided by ffrosch:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.rename(columns={col:col.split("_")[-1]},inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get that done using `rename` with a lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C_A':list('abc'),'C_B':list('abc'),'C_C':list('abc')})
print(df)

  C_A C_B C_C
0   a   a   a
1   b   b   b
2   c   c   c

df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1], inplace=True)
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  a  a  a
1  b  b  b
2  c  c  c
```